# Visual Studio Code for the Web and Salesforce CLI

Tags: salesforce

No Salesforce Extension Packs are available; am I wrong in concluding the web version of Visual Studio Code is useless for Salesforce development at this time?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

using VS Code in the browser as a text editor certainly feels handicapped after being used to the tooling provided by the Salesforce Extensions.

Salesforce certainly seems aware of this and the benefits of a browser based code editor. In June 2020 Salesforce announced a pilot of Code Builder, which is a browser based version of VS Code with the Salesforce extensions built into it.

At Dreamforce this year (2021) it was announced that a beta Code Builder would become available in Spring 22. The spring 22 release notes have recently been published. While it doesn't seem to mention Code Builder, it is clearly something that has been in the works for a while and could be seen soon. Keep your eyes peeled, and if anyone else has any further information I'd love to hear it!